# GWTTestCase with RequestFactory Returning 404

Tags: gwt, junit, requestfactory, gwttestcase

I cannot get RequestFactory to work with GWTTestCase. I see the following:

```
[WARN] 404 - POST /com.traviswebb.MyApp.JUnit/gwtRequest (127.0.0.1) 1439 bytes
```

In my MyAppJUnit.gwt.xml file, I have this:

```
<servlet path='/gwtRequest' class='com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.server.RequestFactoryServlet'/>
```

When I run it in the browser, it just requests `/myApp/gwtRequest` because I have `rename-to` set in the module file. I tried setting this same thing in the JUnit module but it has no effect. In desperation I even tried adding

```
<url-pattern>/com.traviswebb.MyApp.JUnit/gwtRequest</url-pattern>
```

to my web.xml but that didn't work either. Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my usual Stackoverflow process, I am again answering my own question. As a last resort I checked what version of `maven-surefire-plugin` I was using and it was actually 2.5. This is over two years old! This is what I get for copying code straight from a tutorial. Anyway, I upgraded to 2.12 and the problem vanished with no configuration changes.

Comment: Have you tried using the `gwt:test` goal instead of `surefire:test`? I typically leave my browser-ish tests to `gwt:test` as it is generally easier to adapt to running tests on remote browsers instead of just in htmlunit, and the gwt-maven-plugin is easier to keep up to date with the rest of gwt

Comment: I tried using `gwt:test` but I had the same problem. Unfortunately for science, my appetite for debugging through maven plugin hell has waned, as I'm now able to get my work done.

Comment: Fair enough - glad you got it working. I don't currently have any projects freely available that use `gwt:test` and rf, but should make one as a reference for how this can work...